# PHP Number Guessing Game

Tags: php, variables, formatting, format

PHP code problem.

I dug through stack exchange already, but most of the solutions I found were in regards to something I have working. I can accurately get the output to show "guess is too high" or "guess is too low" results. However, where I am stuck is in trying to get the numbers to update.

My code is setup this way "I'm thinking of a number between lowerNumber and higherNumber."

I'm trying to get the appropriate variable's value to update every time a guess is made. So if my number is 23 and someone guesses 12, the next time the page loads it'll be something along the lines of "Too low! Number is between 12 and 100." And then if they guess say 30, which is too high, it'll output "Too high! Number is between 12 and 30."

Currently if I make a guess, it'll update the correct value, but it changes the other to a blank value. If I set:

```
$higher = 100;
$lower = 1;
```

just below the $randomNum (which currently is declared instead of random) then it'll change the values back to either 1 or 100 while it updates the other.

Could anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong?
I've been working on this for eight hours and still cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.... I would be very grateful to know what I need to do to make it work.

```
<?php

$randomNum = 23;


if(isset($_POST['myGuess'])) {
    $myGuess = $_POST['myGuess'];
    $higher = "";
    $lower = "";

    if($myGuess > $randomNum){
        echo "Too high!";
        $higher = $_POST['myGuess'];
        $lower = $_POST['lower'];
    } else if ($myGuess < $randomNum){
        echo "Too low!";
        $lower = $_POST['myGuess'];
        $higher = $_POST['higher'];
    } else if ($myGuess === $randomNum) {
        echo "Good job! That is my number!";
    } 
} else {
$lower = 1;
$higher = 100;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<header>
<style>
#wrapper {
height: 450px; width: 550px; background-color: black; color: white;"
}
.box {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}
p {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.inputs {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
</style>
</header>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box"><p>I am thinking of a number between 
    <?php echo $lower; 
    ?>
    and
    <?php echo $higher; 
    ?>
    .</p><br>
    <form action="1to100.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="lower" value="<?php $lower ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="higher" value="<?php $higher ?>">
        <input type="text" name="myGuess" class="inputs"><br>
        <input type="submit" class="inputs" value="GUESS!"><br>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three errors on this code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lower" value="<?php $lower ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="higher" value-"<?php $higher ?>">
```

The `<?php $lower` should be `<?php echo $lower`, idem with `$higher`. And there is a - instead of a = after the second value attribute. The correct code is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lower" value="<?php echo $lower ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="higher" value="<?php echo $higher ?>">
```

Comment: I fixed the -. Another question though. Just above the input's is where I'm echoing out the current value of higher and lower.

Would I still need to echo in the input despite that?

Comment: Yes, the echo is need in the input value attribute because your are printing out the value of the $lower and $higher variable to the form html.

Comment: The echo print the variable value to the html. You can use it every time you want, it's well done

Comment: This worked very well, thank you for answering my question. I just had to try it out and think about it for a bit for it to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="lower" value="<?php $lower ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="higher" value-"<?php $higher ?>">
```

You're not printing out the variables to lower and higher.

Comment: I'm echoing them out a few lines just above.

Would there be a more efficient way to echo them out? Or is printing the variables to lower and higher in this case different from echoing them out?

Comment: You have to echo them out each time you want it on the html page.